# Is there a way to make a user list?

Tags: java, list, jgrasp

For my coding class I have to build a shopping list by having the user enter the number of items they need and then each item (one at a time). I then have to output the final shopping list in a multi-line dialogue box (one item per line). I have the first two parts done where users enter the number of items and what items they would like, but can't figure out how to output all the items. Any help would be great, thanks! Also, I am using jgrasp and we don't use println to output messages.

I've tried Output.showMessage("Shopping list \n" + items); and
Output.showMessage(items.toString());

```
public class ShoppingList
    {
        public static void main (String [] args)
        { 

          String items;
          int numItems, count;

          numItems = Input.readInt("Enter number of items: ");

          count = 0;
          while (count < numItems)
          {

             items = Input.readString("Enter item: ");

             count = count + 1;


          }//end while

          Output.showMessage(items.toString());      

       } //end main
    } //end ShoppingList
```

The output should show a list of user entered items like:

Shopping List:
Bananas
Milk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Items` cannot be of `string` type because whenever the line

```
items = Input.readString("Enter item: ");
```

is executed, the previous value of `items` is overwritten.
If you are allowed to for your homework, it's ideal to make `items` an array otherwise you would have to change the previous statement to

```
items += Input.readString("Enter item: ");
items += '\n';
```

**Note:**`items` here is one long String.